# Sequential compactness, the other direction.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

**Proposition.** A set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact iff every sequence of points of the set has a subsequence that converges to a point of the set itself.

**Attempt.** $\Longrightarrow$ Suppose $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact set. Then $S$ is bounded. Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be any sequence in $S$. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, we can find a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ that converges to a point $a$ in $S$.

$\Longleftarrow$ Suppose every sequence of the set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ has a subsequence that converges to a point of $S$. Then... ?

I am kind of stuck in the other direction. Any hints from you would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your first definition of compactness? Closed and bounded?

Comment: http://www.econ.brown.edu/fac/Mark_Dean/Maths_RA5_10.pdf has what you need. Should be sufficient.

Comment: Well, thanks for Googling that for me. But is there a way to prove the other direction without introducing "totally bounded"?

Comment: Totally bounded and bounded coincide in Euclidean space, so I suppose you don't need to worry about it too much.

Comment: Okay, thanks again. I might be kind of picky. Is there a way to prove this without using contradiction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show: If every sequence in $S$ has a subsequence converging to a point in $S$, then $S$ is closed and bounded.
Try showing the contrapositive:

1. If $S$ is not closed, then $S$ does not contain all its limit points.  So find a limit point $a$ of $S$ such that $a \not \in S$, and then find $x_n \to a$, with $x_n \in S$, which means no subsequence of $x_n$ converges to a point in $S$.
2. If $S$ is not bounded, then for all $n$, pick a point $x_n$ such that $\left\|{x_n}\right\| > n$.  But then for any $x \in S$, by triangle, inequality,
   $$
   \|x_n - x\| \ge \|x_n\| - \|x\| > n - \|x\| \to \infty
   $$
   as $n \to \infty$, so $x_n$ does not converge to any point in $x$.

Comment: Very nice. It is kind of like proving the other direction of the Heine-Borel theorem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The following is applicable to any metric space:

1. If $K$ is sequentially compact, and $K\subset\bigcup_{j\in I}G_j$ is an open cover, show that there exists some $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in K$ we have $B_\delta(x)\subset G_j$ for some $j\in I$. ($\delta$ is sometimes referred to as the [Lebesgue number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma) of the cover.)
2. If $K$ is sequentially compact, then for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $n\in\Bbb N$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in K$ such that $K\subset\bigcup_{m=1}^n B_\epsilon(x_m)$. (Edit: well, we don't need to call it total-boundedness, right?)
3. Combine the two results to show that if $K$ is sequentially compact, then every open cover has a finite subcover.